# Undesired outcome in a students' career query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to implement a database structure to follow a students' career to prevent having to duplicate users. I got a database setup with the following tables:

### `users` *(not necessarily students)*

| name | type | settings | references | notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id | uuid | pk | class_years.assignee_id class_years.sub_assignee_id class_year_students.student_id |  |
| firstName | varchar |  |  |  |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |  |

### `classes`

| name | type | settings | references | notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id | uuid | pk | class_years.class_id |  |
| class | varchar |  |  |  |

### `class_years`

| name | type | settings | references | notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id | uuid | pk | class_year_students.class_year_id |  |
| class_id | uuid |  | classes.id |  |
| year_id | uuid |  | years.id |  |
| assignee_id | uuid |  | users.id | Responsible for the class |
| sub_assignee_id | uuid |  | users.id | Helping for the weight of the responsibility |

### `class_year_students`

| name | type | settings | references | notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| class_year_id | uuid |  | class_years.id |  |
| student_id | uuid |  | users.id |  |

### `years`

| name | type | settings | references | notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id | uuid | pk | class_years.year_id |  |
| beginning | datetime |  |  | Schoolyear is from September |
| ending | datetime |  |  | Schoolyear is until June |

If there are any thoughts on my structure, please do share them!

I'm trying to make a query that can track the students' career. However I'm getting multiple rows of the same user. I expected to have 1 row per user. I'm also trying to figure out as to why it does this.

```sql
SELECT
  s.*,
  json_build_object(
    c.class,
    json_agg(json_build_object('beginning', y.beginning, 'ending', y.ending))
  ) AS data,
  row_to_json(a.*) AS assignee,
  row_to_json(sa.*) AS sub_assignee
FROM
  users AS s
  LEFT JOIN "class_year_students" AS cys ON cys."student_id" = s.id
  LEFT JOIN "class_years" AS cy ON cy.id = cys."class_year_id"
  LEFT JOIN "classes" AS c ON c.id = cy."class_id"
  LEFT JOIN "years" AS y ON y.id = cy."year_id"
  LEFT JOIN "users" AS a ON a.id = cy."assignee_id"
  LEFT JOIN "users" AS sa ON sa.id = cy."sub_assignee_id"
GROUP BY
  s.id,
  c.class,
  a.*,
  sa.*
```

## Sample output

```
                  id                  | firstName |                                  data                                                               |                                  assignee                                  |                                  sub_assignee 
--------------------------------------+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 037aca84-0324-4363-a6ab-9f4c227b8a4b | Juana     | {"1OR2" : [{"beginning" : "2016-10-01T05:00:00+02:00", "ending" : "2017-07-30T05:00:00+02:00"}]}    | {"id" : "2a821860-e690-4831-9523-8cdc5b8d22d3", "firstName" : "Erick"}     | {"id" : "34fbc10f-6693-4de7-9702-4de88f665fcd", "firstName" : "Bret"}
 037aca84-0324-4363-a6ab-9f4c227b8a4b | Juana     | {"1OR2" : [{"beginning" : "2003-10-01T05:00:00+02:00", "ending" : "2004-07-30T05:00:00+02:00"}]}    | {"id" : "47897467-83de-4aba-9b41-85160a1c536d", "firstName" : "Muriel"}    | {"id" : "35ea26d0-79ee-47f5-b239-7a42f9bd79fc", "firstName" : "Cassandra"}
 037aca84-0324-4363-a6ab-9f4c227b8a4b | Juana     | {"1OR2" : [{"beginning" : "2019-10-01T05:00:00+02:00", "ending" : "2020-07-30T05:00:00+02:00"}]}    | {"id" : "4d9e1133-7e09-456a-bff6-e3d2911e260b", "firstName" : "Colton"}    | {"id" : "ad537084-c2c3-45f1-bf0f-a5443d813af0", "firstName" : "Arvilla"}
 037aca84-0324-4363-a6ab-9f4c227b8a4b | Juana     | {"1OR2" : [{"beginning" : "2018-10-01T05:00:00+02:00", "ending" : "2019-07-30T05:00:00+02:00"}]}    | {"id" : "af42d209-ad25-4edd-aecb-a02a5320ab2e", "firstName" : "Velva"}     | {"id" : "0d10d030-9b58-40a9-9d98-96a6780f7041", "firstName" : "Don"}
 037aca84-0324-4363-a6ab-9f4c227b8a4b | Juana     | {"1OR3" : [{"beginning" : "2016-10-01T05:00:00+02:00", "ending" : "2017-07-30T05:00:00+02:00"}]}    | {"id" : "2a821860-e690-4831-9523-8cdc5b8d22d3", "firstName" : "Erick"}     | {"id" : "af42d209-ad25-4edd-aecb-a02a5320ab2e", "firstName" : "Velva"}
 037aca84-0324-4363-a6ab-9f4c227b8a4b | Juana     | {"1R1" : [{"beginning" : "2016-10-01T05:00:00+02:00", "ending" : "2017-07-30T05:00:00+02:00"}]}     | {"id" : "c2d2c85d-9381-498e-b0dd-96de898ce01b", "firstName" : "Jana"}      | {"id" : "36b3d24e-302b-4fc1-8c7f-9fc0e657e9bf", "firstName" : "Thaddeus"}
 037aca84-0324-4363-a6ab-9f4c227b8a4b | Juana     | {"1R3" : [{"beginning" : "2016-10-01T05:00:00+02:00", "ending" : "2017-07-30T05:00:00+02:00"}]}     | {"id" : "3f901df2-d30f-4fd3-80ca-2f4b34717360", "firstName" : null}        | {"id" : "36b3d24e-302b-4fc1-8c7f-9fc0e657e9bf", "firstName" : "Thaddeus"}
```

I struggle to understand how to see and debug how a query is behaving the way it is. What seems logic to me isn't the output I desired. How do you prevent that from happening and what steps do you undertake when this occurs to root out the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `I expected to have 1 row per user.` In that case you should `GROUP BY s.id` only; the rest will be dependent on it and/or packed into json payload.

Comment: Upon doing that I get a syntax error: `column "c.class" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

Comment: What was the expected output? Obviously, when a user has followed several classes over several years, you will output multiple rows. What is the problem with that? Isn't a "career" like that?

Comment: Expected result is fine, but we need the matching sample data too.

Comment: The expected output was to have the career as json in data with the years as an array and the class as keys.

Comment: Added sample data output.

Comment: @wildplasser I tried it here and it indeed is showing an unique row per student here. However I can't seem to relate the years within the `class` key. E.g. a student can be in 2 years in the same class if they fail. I can't seem to nest the `json_agg` function to produce an array.